# How to create mapping of 2nd level child node in Spicelib/Parsley for Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, parsley

I have an XML structure that looks like this:

```
<ROOT>
  <P att1="" att2="">
    <KEYWORDS>
      <K name="" />
      <K name="" />
    </KEYWORDS>
  </P>
  <P att1="" att2="">
    <KEYWORDS>
      <K name="" />
    </KEYWORDS>
  </P>
</ROOT>
```

I would like to map the P nodes and the K nodes, but not the KEYWORDS nodes.

I have a class for the P and K nodes

```
package
{
    [XmlMapping(elementName="P", ignoreUnmappedAttributes="true", ignoreUnmappedChildren="true")]
    public class Package
    {
      [ChoiceType("Keyword")]
      public var keywords:Array;
    }
}

package 
{
    [XmlMapping(elementName="K", ignoreUnmappedAttributes="true", ignoreUnmappedChildren="true")]
    public class Keyword 
    {
        public var name:String;
    }
}
```

And then I have my mapper:

```
var mapper:XmlObjectMapper = XmlObjectMappings
    .forUnqualifiedElements()
    .withRootElement(Package)
    .mappedClasses(Keyword)
    .build();
```

But this always results in keywords of the P class being null. The only way I have gotten this to work is to create a "throwaway" class called Keywords that I map to the keywords property of Package and that class also has a keywords property that is mapped to the Keyword class. And then in Package I use a setter to pull out the actual keywords I want like so:

```
//mapping the new Keywords class
var mapper:XmlObjectMapper = XmlObjectMappings
    .forUnqualifiedElements()
    .withRootElement(Package)
    .mappedClasses(Keywords, Keyword)
    .build();

//the new Package class
package 
{
    [XmlMapping(elementName="P", ignoreUnmappedAttributes="true", ignoreUnmappedChildren="true")]
    public class Package 
    {
        private var _keywords:Array;

        [ChoiceType("Keywords")]
        public function set keywords(value:Array):void 
        {
          //there is always only one KEYWORDS node
          _keywords = value[0].keywords
        }

        public function get keywords():Array 
        {
            return _keywords;
        }
    }
}

//the new intermediary Keywords class
package
{
    [XmlMapping(elementName="KEYWORDS", ignoreUnmappedAttributes="true", ignoreUnmappedChildren="true")]
    public class Keywords 
    {
        [ChoiceType("Keyword")]
        public var keywords:Array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Too many letters, the problem is not clear. What do you want to get as the result? A list of P nodes by specific K.@name?

Comment: I want to create an XmlObjectMappings instance that will map K elements to a keywords property on the package class. From what I can tell for parsley though, you can "drill down" a level to get only the K elements. You have to map the KEYWORDS elements to a class and then the K elements in there to a class. I would rather skip mapping the KEYWORDS element, but still grab the child K elements. Just not sure if that's possible or not using the spicelib libraries

Comment: Let me rephrase. I can help you find all **P** nodes that contain **K** nodes with a given **@name** property (and filter out the ones that does not satisfy the condition). Unless your ultimate goal **is** to use  that weird thing you are trying to use whatever it is for.

Comment: I specifically need to use the parsley framework. :( Which I do not like at all. I think I just have to create a custom mapper within their framework.